# Python Django Static not showing

Tags: django

I tried many solutions available in stock overflow too but non of it solved my problems.Django is my very first framework right after learning HTML,CSS,python(basics)
I don't know what I am doing wrong please help me fix it here is my code
Here is my folder structure:

[folder structure][1]

Here is my settings,URL,HTML code

````
   STATICFILES_DIR=[
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"static")
   #BASE_DIR/'static'
   ]




   from django.urls import path
   from . import views
   from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns 
   urlpatterns=[
   path('', views.home, name='home'),
   path('customer',views.customer,name='customer'),
   path('products',views.products,name='products')
   ]
   urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()


   {% load static %}
   <!DOCTYPE HTML>
   <html lang="en">
   <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Dash Board</title>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
 
   </head>
   <body>
   {% include "navbar.html" %}
   {% block content%}

   {% endblock %}
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>

  </html>```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/65Z9x.png
````

Answer (score 0):

Your static folders should be in the app folder, not in the general templates folder, then Django cant find them. In development Django will search each app for its [static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development).

I would also recommend grouping your templates in the app itself, that makes it easier to work with later on when there are a lot of templates.

When deploying, you can run `python manage.py collectstatic` to collect them in the defined path from `settings.py`.

Structure example:

```
.
├── ...
├── crml
│   ├── templates
│   ├── static          # here 
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
└── ...
```